# IIS Basic Auth Configuration .NET Core 2.1 application

Tags: iis, .net-core, basic-authentication

I have a .NET Core 2.1 application that is running on IIS with Basic Authentication and Windows Authentication configured. Windows Authentication is working as expected. When I disable Windows Authentication and only use Basic Authentication the application does not work as expected. It prompts for credentials when visiting the index.html page and prompts again when you go to the swashbuckle UI of the API. When you try to use any of the API Endpoints it prompts for credentials and continues to prompt for credentials like it doesn't remember the user.

I have this Middleware logging what is happening

```
  public class UserInfoMiddleWare
  {
    private readonly ILogger<UserInfoMiddleWare> _logger;
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public UserInfoMiddleWare(ILogger<UserInfoMiddleWare> logger, RequestDelegate next)
    {
      _logger = logger;
      _next = next;
    }

    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
    {

      this._logger.LogError("UserInfoMiddleWare!!!!!!");

      try
      {

      var userIdentity = context.User?.Identity;
        this._logger.LogError($"user exists {(userIdentity != null)}");
        var loginName = context.User?.LoginName();
        this._logger.LogError($"LoginName {loginName}");
        var name = userIdentity?.Name;
        this._logger.LogError($"name {name}");

      var identityIsAuthenticated = userIdentity?.IsAuthenticated;
        this._logger.LogError($"identityIsAuthenticated {identityIsAuthenticated}");

        var identityAuthenticationType = userIdentity?.AuthenticationType;
        this._logger.LogError($"identityAuthenticationType {identityAuthenticationType}");
    }
      catch (Exception e)
      {
        this._logger.LogError(e, "bad middleware!");
      }

      await _next(context);

  }
```

This is a sample output I am getting in my logs

```
[Error] UserInfoMiddleWare!!!!!!
[Error] user exists True
[Error] LoginName 
[Error] name 
[Error] identityIsAuthenticated False
[Error] identityAuthenticationType
```

**Edit:**
After doing some reading it looks like .NET Core does not support Basic Auth even if IIS is the proxy. If someone could confirm that with some documentation I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASP.NET Core Module is designed to only forward Windows authentication token,

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/aspnet-core-module?view=aspnetcore-2.1

Not sure if in .NET Core 2.2 they plan to change that.